# Do we have an SNMP MIB for URIB

Tags: routing, snmp, management, rfc

As we know that URIB (Unicast RIB) holds various route entries that have been added by routing protocols running on the box (like BGP, EIGRP, etc). Typically, "show ip route" woudl display all entries that are present in the URIB. Does anyone know if we can access these using (SNMP) MIB objects? Can someone point me to the RFC/draft, if there is one?

Comment: are you looking for [ipRouteDest](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21.1.1#oidContent)? (RFC 1213), or perhaps something else like [RFC 4293](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4293)?

Comment: Mike, yes, this is what I was looking for. As always, thank you! Brett elaborated on that as well!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the `ipRouteTable` OID in the RFC1213-MIB?  [(OID  number 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21#oidContent)

I utilize this to pull the routing table out of several devices.

It is referenced by [RFC 1213](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1213.txt) which, on page 33, gives the following information:

```
      -- The IP routing table contains an entry for each route
      -- presently known to this entity.

      ipRouteTable OBJECT-TYPE
          SYNTAX  SEQUENCE OF IpRouteEntry
          ACCESS  not-accessible
          STATUS  mandatory
          DESCRIPTION
                  "This entity's IP Routing table."
          ::= { ip 21 }

      ipRouteEntry OBJECT-TYPE
          SYNTAX  IpRouteEntry
          ACCESS  not-accessible
          STATUS  mandatory
          DESCRIPTION
                  "A route to a particular destination."
          INDEX   { ipRouteDest }
          ::= { ipRouteTable 1 }

      IpRouteEntry ::=
          SEQUENCE {
              ipRouteDest
                  IpAddress,
              ipRouteIfIndex
                  INTEGER,
              ipRouteMetric1
                  INTEGER,
              ipRouteMetric2
                  INTEGER,
              ipRouteMetric3
                  INTEGER,
              ipRouteMetric4
                  INTEGER,
              ipRouteNextHop
                  IpAddress,
              ipRouteType
                  INTEGER,
              ipRouteProto
                  INTEGER,
              ipRouteAge
                  INTEGER,
              ipRouteMask
                  IpAddress,
              ipRouteMetric5
                  INTEGER,
```

Comment: Brett, thank you! Yes, this is what I was looking for (+1).